# Received html format instead json

Tags: android, html, json

SERVER_URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json",

URL = "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/".

SERVER_URL it is address where are from i want get json data. URL it's example address. I don't change code, i only change address. When i change it to url, it's work fine, but when i change to SERVER_URL i received html format of data.
Someone have explanation for it, please.

````
public class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private static final String SERVER_URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
        private static final String url = "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
        private static final String TAG = "JSONAsyncTask";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(SERVER_URL);
            [![enter image description here][1]][1]Log.i(TAG, "testers url type - " +url+": "+ "jsonStr\n" + jsonStr);

            
            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i(TAG, "testers: Exception " + e);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        }
    }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hypuq.jpg
````

Comment: Examle of logcat - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hypuq.jpg

Comment: Replace `http://` to `https://`. You received HTML data for redirection from HTTP to HTTPS. Probably handle the redirection or use HTTPS.

Comment: it's works, thank you a lot. Please share your answer i will rate it, if you want.

Comment: sure, glad that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably received a HTTP 301 response code to redirect from `http://` to `https://`.

[RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.2) does specify that server's response could contain hyperlinks to the new URIs, probably in the form of [meta refresh](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html); and user-agents or clients could choose to follow the redirections or not, hence what you have here.

In your case, you could probably handle the redirections from your `HttpHandler` class (i.e. enabling [`HttpURLConnection.instanceFollowRedirects`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection#instanceFollowRedirects)), or just use `https://` version of the URL.